# show loading dialog on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

In my Grails application, I would like to show some kind of visual indicator (possibly a modal dialog) when an AJAX request is in progress.

I use JQuery for all my AJAX requests, currently they are all triggered using Grails tags, but I expect I'll eventually need to use the JQuery functions directly (e.g.`$.ajax`).

Is there some way I make this loading dialog appear/disappear each time an AJAX requesting is starts/completes without having to repeat the code in every place I make an AJAX call?

Comment: Check this http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#loading_animation").bind({
    ajaxStart: function() { $(this).show(); },
    ajaxStop: function() {  $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would switch over to explicitly using jquery.  With jQuery, you can configure settings that all ajax requests will use

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
     // do mask here
   },
   complete: function(xhr,textStatus){
     // remove mask here
   }

});
```

I found all this [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It's possible that will work when launching AJAX requests using the Graila tags, becaue it's still ultimately calling the JQuery functions.